# Erro while confugure Angular Js with eclipse mars (64) bit

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

From last 2 days I have been trying to configure angularJs plug ins with eclipse mars (64 bit) but I have faced following error while installation.

I don't able to understand why this is happen , Please provide solution if anyone faced this kind of problem earlier.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Error

***error occurred while collecting items to be installed***

session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/plugins/ternjs_1.2.0.201603071119.jar.
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 15860647; received: 8215638
Unable to read repository at http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/plugins/tern.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.embed.linux.gtk.x86_64_1.2.0.201603071119.jar.
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 12496015; received: 4025126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling the plugin completely and Reinstall it. I've faced same issue reinstalling fixed it.

Comment: I don't this its issue with installation

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. In my case it is due to

> angularjs plugin for eclipse self signed certificate

Try to download plugin and install from eclipse. Below link worked for me

https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/releases